# Proving some relations regarding the continuous function

Tags: functions, continuity

Could you give me any ideas or tips, how to get this task done? I find it very complicated and thus ask for your help.

The task is as follows:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $f$ in $[0,n]$ be a continuous function, whereby $f(0) = f(n) $.

Prove, that there exist numbers $x_1, x_2 \in [0, n]$, in which case
$$ x_2 - x_1 = 1$$ and $$f(x_2) = f(x_1).$$

Comment: If $n=1$ and $x_2=1$ and $x_1=0$ then the given relation is right

Comment: Hint: Put $g(x)=f(x)-f(1+x)$ on $[0,n-1]$. Compute $g(0)+g(1)+\cdots+g(n-1)$. Can we have $g(x)>0$ for all $x$ ? or $g(x)<0$ for all $x$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but it works. The idea is to use the mean value theorem and binary search:

W.l.o.g. you can assume there is a $c \in [0,n] $ s.t. $f(c) = \max \limits_{x \in [0,n]} f(x)$ and $f(c) \neq f(0)$.

Now we look at $g:= \frac{f(0)-f(c)}{2}$.

By Mean value thm we know there is a $d_0$ in $(0,c)$ s.t. $f(d_0) = g$. Analogously there is $\bar{d_0}$ in $(c,n)$ s.t. $f(\bar{d_0}) = g$.

If $d_0 -\bar{d_0} = 1$ we are done, if $d_0 -\bar{d_0} > 1$ we look in $(0,d_0)$ and $(\bar{d_0},n)$ and if $d_0 -\bar{d_0} < 1$ we look in $(d_0,c)$ and $(c,\bar{d_0})$.

Thus by recursively using binary search we approach the limit values $z$ and $\bar{z}$ with $\bar{z} = z+1$. Because $f$ is continuous it follows $f(\bar{z}) = f(z+1)$ and we are done.